# Apache mod_cache: Strip/ignore (only) Google Analytics cookies

Tags: apache-2.2, cookies, mod-cache

[Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) has the possibility to [strip certain cookies](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleRemovingSomeCookies) from the request before deciding if a request is non-cachable because it contains cookies. Is there such a thing for Apache's mod_cache?

Consider this situation: Apache 2.2 is a reverse proxy with lots of configuration (multiple VirtualHosts, 4 backend servers, authentication based on Host and path) that I really like - because it works.

Now to speed up delivery of a Django site, I would like to cache all requests to a certain VirtualHost - except those that carry the Django session cookie (e.g. logged in staff requests). Now the request obviously [Vary](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html#overview)s with cookies, e.g. a logged in user with cookie is always given a freshly rendered page while someone without cookies is given a cached response.

So `Vary: cookie` would be the correct cache control header to do exactly that: Always freshly render when cookies present.
BUT then there is Google Analytics (GA) (and other cookie-based tracking mechanisms like eTracker) that *always* sets a cookie.

**Can Apache ignore that GA-cookie** and Vary on the Django session cookie??

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can say (from my own personal tests) mod_cache in Apache 2.2.3 does not Vary with any cookie. It ends up serving anonymous-like pages to logged in users because ignores their cookie.